# During gradle test show standard out and err only for failed tests

Tags: testing, gradle, travis-ci

I have a large test suite running on travis-ci, which has a textual output. I would like to configure gradle in a way that only for failed tests, the standard output and standard error streams are displayed. For all other tests which have been executed correctly, this should not happen so that the console is not polluted with that noise.

I am aware how to enable or disable the standard output/error logging, but I am unsure how to make this dependend on the test result.

Comment: Not [tag:travis-ci] related, this is purely a [tag:gradle] question

Comment: Which testing framework do you use? Do you know whether the output is written using a logging framework or is it printed directly (System.out) to the stdout/stderr?

Comment: I am using JUnit which is executed as part of a gradle test task.

Answer (score 7):

This can be archived with following gradle config

```groovy
project.test {
  def outputCache = new LinkedList<String>()

  beforeTest { TestDescriptor td -> outputCache.clear() }    // clear everything right before the test starts

  onOutput { TestDescriptor td, TestOutputEvent toe ->       // when output is coming put it in the cache
    outputCache.add(toe.getMessage())
    while (outputCache.size() > 1000) outputCache.remove() // if we have more than 1000 lines -> drop first
  }

  /** after test -> decide what to print */
  afterTest { TestDescriptor td, TestResult tr ->
    if (tr.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE && outputCache.size() > 0) {
        println()
        println(" Output of ${td.className}.${td.name}:")
        outputCache.each { print(" > $it") }
    }
  }
}
```

Git repo: https://github.com/calliduslynx/gradle-log-on-failure

Original found here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/show-stderr-for-failed-tests/8463/7

Comment: The above code doesn't seem to magically suppress output, instead it only collects it additionally to what Gradle does already and prints it afterwards. That's why `events /*'started',*/ 'passed', 'failed'` is additionally used in the linked sources. Only that actually reduces output, because `standard_*` is not part of the given values.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following configuration block to your *build.gradle* file:

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
               TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
               TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
               TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showCauses true
        showExceptions true
        showStackTraces true
        showStandardStreams true
    }
}
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogEvent.html).

Comment: You have to keep only 'TestLogEvent.FAILED' to show failed only; it won't still show stdout and stderr without `showStandardStreams true`, but that applies to non failed as well

Comment: Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogging.html#setShowStandardStreams-boolean-) for `showStandardStreams`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Test.beforeTest`, `Test.onOutput` methods require a Groovy `Closure` object, one can use the compatibility method (`closureOf`, `KotlinClosure2`, etc.) but I prefered to write my own listener in pure Kotlin.

```kotlin
import my.conventions.FailedTestLogger.Companion.logStdOutOnFailure

// ...

tasks {
    withType<Test>().configureEach {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging {
            showStackTraces = true
            exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
            events = setOf(
                TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
            )
        }
        logStdOutOnFailure()
    }
}
```

````kotlin
package my.conventions

import org.gradle.api.logging.Logging
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestDescriptor
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestOutputEvent
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestOutputListener
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

/**
 * Only logs test output when a test fails.
 *
 * Example configuration
 *
 * ```kotlin
 * tasks.test {
 *     useJUnitPlatform()
 *     testLogging {
 *         showStackTraces = true
 *         exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
 *         events = setOf(
 *             TestLogEvent.FAILED,
 *             TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
 *         )
 *     }
 *     logStdOutOnFailure()
 * }
 * ```
 */
class FailedTestLogger : TestListener, TestOutputListener {
    private val testOutputs: MutableMap<TestDescriptor, MutableList<TestOutputEvent>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    override fun beforeSuite(test: TestDescriptor) {
    }

    override fun afterSuite(testDescriptor: TestDescriptor, testResult: TestResult) {
        testOutputs.clear()
    }

    override fun beforeTest(testDescriptor: TestDescriptor) {}

    override fun afterTest(test: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult) {
        if (result.resultType === TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE) {
            LOGGER.error(buildString {
                append("## FAILURE: ")
                test.className?.let {
                    append(it)
                    append(".")
                }
                append(test.displayName)
            })
            for (output in testOutputs.getOrDefault(test, listOf())) {
                when (output.destination) {
                    TestOutputEvent.Destination.StdOut -> print(output.message)
                    TestOutputEvent.Destination.StdErr -> System.err.print(output.message)
                }

            }
            for (exception in result.exceptions) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        testOutputs.remove(test)
    }

    override fun onOutput(test: TestDescriptor, outputEvent: TestOutputEvent) {
        testOutputs.compute(test) { _, value ->
            (value ?: mutableListOf()).also {
                it.add(outputEvent)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = Logging.getLogger(FailedTestLogger::class.java)

        /**
         * Configure the test task to only logs test output when a test fails.
         *
         * Should be used at the end.
         */
        fun AbstractTestTask.logStdOutOnFailure() {
            if (!project.providers.systemProperty("idea.active").map { it.toBoolean() }.getOrElse(false)) {
                testLogging {
                    showStandardStreams = false
                }

                FailedTestLogger().also {
                    addTestListener(it)
                    addTestOutputListener(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
````