# Full test logging only for failed tests in Gradle

Tags: gradle

When I run tests in Gradle I expect:

- when a test passes just one-line info `com.me.MyTest > myTest PASSED`
- when a test fails I expect all standard streams and stacktraces to be displayed

  ```
  com.me.MyTest > myTest STANDARD_OUT
      ...
  com.me.MyTest > myTest STANDARD_ERROR
      ...
  com.me.MyTest > myTest FAILED
      <full stacktrace>
  ```

I achieve the second by setting:

```
tasks.withType(Test).testLogging { TestLoggingContainer container ->
    container.with {
        events FAILED, PASSED, SKIPPED, STANDARD_ERROR, STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat = FULL
        showCauses = true
        showExceptions = true
        showStackTraces = true
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

but these settings pollute the logs of `PASSED` tests with `STANDARD_ERROR` and `STANDARD_OUT`.

**Can I somehow mute `STANDARD_ERROR` and `STANDARD_OUT` events for `PASSED` tests?**

Comment: Possible dup of "[During gradle test show standard out and err only for failed tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558340/90527)"